# why do i need to add [exponent - 1] after 'stack'?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently studying recursive functions in Javascript, and for the most part I understand what recursion is and how to use it, but I have one question: Why do I need "why do i need to add [exponent - 1] after 'stack'?" here is the code:

```
var stack = [];

// Here is our recursive function
function power(base, exponent) {
    // Base case 
    if ( exponent === 0 ) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Recursive case
    else {
        //Why do I need [exponent - 1]?
        **stack[exponent - 1] = base * power(base, exponent - 1)**;
        return stack[exponent - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Because an array in JavaScript must start from element 0. But you don't need that to calculate power.

Comment: I understand that array elements start at 0, but why [exponent - 1]? Could you clarify? The reason I'm using that is cause I'm adding the results to stack[];

Comment: Because otherwise the lowest call to `stack[x]` would be `stack[1]` and it would give a error because `stack[0]` was yet to be defined.

Comment: Ahhh I think I see it now, so you're telling me that [exponent - 1] isn't subtracting(let's say 10) from 1, but rather I am assigning exponent(10) to 1st array element?

Comment: if ur problem solved plz select the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because

```
power(any_number, 0) = 1, (constant)

stack[0] = power(any_number, 0) = 1,
stack[1] = any_number * stack[0],
stack[2] = any_number * stack[1],
stack[3] = any_number * stack[2],
...
```

this is how power() function works in Mathematics.
the power of number to zero (n^0) = 1,
next every power is before power multiplied by base one more time.

You understand?

**EDIT**

Answering your comment, you almost understood from what you wrote.

It's like this:

```
n^0 = 1
n^1 = n * n^0 = n * 1
n^2 = n * n^1 = n * n * 1
n^3 = n * n^2 = n * n * n * 1
n^4 = n * n^3 = n * n * n * n * 1
...
```

Every next is `n * previous` (// Recursive case)

With the exception that n^0 is always equal to 1 and ends this function. (// Base case)

Is it more clear now?

Comment: Almost but it's still pretty vague to me...ok, so "stack[0] = power(num, 0) = 1" shouldn't 1 be assigned to stack[0];

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out, tell me if I'm wrong. So when I say 
**stack[exponent - 1] = base * power(base, exponent - 1);**    what's happening is the very first result **n^0=1**, is like saying stack[1] therefore the result is actually the 2nd element in stack, so therefore                                               **stack[exponent - 1] = stack[0]** is the same thing as **stack[1 - 1] = stack[0]**. Is that correct?

Comment: I edited the answer to make it more clear. I think now you will understand 100%

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are indexed from `[0, length - 1]`. If we had not subtracted by 0 then the first element of `stack` would have been empty. `exponent` will always be greater than 0 in the `else` case.

Answer (score 1):

you don't really need it, try:

```
var stack = [];

function power(base, exponent) {
    // Base case 
    if ( exponent === 0 ) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Recursive case
    else {
        //[exponent] instead of [exponent - 1]
        stack[exponent] = base * power(base, exponent - 1);
        return stack[exponent];
    }
}
```

however, stack would have an undefined index, so instead you can try

```
var stack = [];

function power(base, exponent) {
    // Base case 
    if ( exponent === 0 ) {
       stack[0] = 1;
    }
    // Recursive case
    else {
        //[exponent] instead of [exponent - 1]
        stack[exponent] = base * power(base, exponent - 1);
    }
    return stack[exponent];
}
alert(power(2,3));
alert(stack);
// stack is now [1, 2, 4, 8]
```